# Just Unit testing in TypeScript: Make an element resizable with jQuery UI widget with a custom handle

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui, jestjs

My function accepts two parameters.  The first parameter is the jQuery object itself.   The second parameter is an HTMLElement.

The purpose of the function is to add resizable features to the element by applying the [jQuery-UI Resizable Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/), with the added option of supplying a custom handle.  Here is the function, which is working as desired,

```ts
const addResizableAndCustomHandleToCustomSelectScrollBars = (
  $: JQueryStatic,
  selectScrollbarsElement: JQuery<HTMLElement>,
  handleId: string
) => {
  // Create handle and attach it to the given element
  const customHandle: HTMLElement = document.createElement("div");
  selectScrollbarsElement.append(customHandle!);

  // add the classes required for the handle by jQueryUI
  customHandle.setAttribute(
    "class",
    "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se"
  );
  customHandle.setAttribute("id", handleId);
  // Wrap the element in a jQuery object...
  const selectScrollJQueryUIObject: JQuery<HTMLElement> = $(
    selectScrollbarsElement
  );
  //and add the Resizable widget with the custom handle created earlier
  selectScrollJQueryUIObject.resizable({
    handles: { s: $(customHandle) },
  });

  // Configure style to put icon in the proper bottom right position of the element.
  customHandle!.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "z-index: 90; left: unset; cursor: s-resize;"
  );
};
```

And here is my unit test:

```ts
import {
  describe,
  afterEach,
  expect,
  it,
  beforeEach,
  jest,
} from "@jest/globals";
import { addResizableAndCustomHandleToCustomSelectScrollBars } from "../../src/utils/utils";
import $ from "jquery";

describe("addResizableAndCustomHandleToCustomSelectScrollBars", () => {
  let selectScrollbarsElement: HTMLElement;
  // let customHandle: HTMLElement;
  let resizableSpy: any;
  let selectScrollBarJQueryObject: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Create and configure the necessary DOM elements
    selectScrollbarsElement = document.createElement("div");
    selectScrollBarJQueryObject = $(selectScrollbarsElement);
    // customHandle = document.createElement("div");

    // Spy on the jQuery resizable function
    resizableSpy = jest.spyOn(selectScrollBarJQueryObject, "resizable");

    // Append the elements to the document
    document.body.appendChild(selectScrollbarsElement);
    // document.body.appendChild(customHandle);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // Clean up the DOM and reset spies after each test
    document.body.removeChild(selectScrollbarsElement);
    // document.body.removeChild(customHandle);
    resizableSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it("should add resizable widget with custom handle", () => {
    // Call the function to be tested
    addResizableAndCustomHandleToCustomSelectScrollBars(
      $,
      $(selectScrollbarsElement),
      "customId"
    );
    const customHandle = $("customId")[0] as HTMLElement;
    // Assert that the custom handle was added to the element
    expect(selectScrollbarsElement.contains(customHandle)).toBe(true);

    // Assert that the jQuery resizable function was called with the expected arguments
    expect(resizableSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      handles: { s: $(customHandle) },
    });

    // Assert that the custom handle has the required classes
    expect(customHandle.classList).toContain("ui-resizable-handle");
    expect(customHandle.classList).toContain("ui-resizable-s");
    expect(customHandle.classList).toContain("ui-resizable-se");
    expect(customHandle.classList).toContain("ui-icon");
    expect(customHandle.classList).toContain("ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se");
  });
});
```

In fact, I have written this unit test a number of ways, but continue to face similar errors:

```
**Property `resizable` does not exist in the provided object**

      25 |
      26 |     // Spy on the jQuery resizable function
    > 27 |     resizableSpy = jest.spyOn(selectScrollBarJQueryObject, "resizable");
```

The JQuery object has an object method called resizable.  It's technically not a function.  But it does return a function.

I have tried writing the test several different ways and face similar errors, some saying that .resizable is not a function.

Would appreciate any help to get this unit test working.